# How to update c# value in Blazor using javascript?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I am wondering is it possible to update `C#` value in `Blazor` using `Javascript`

For example

```
<input type="text" @bind="TestValue" >
<input type="button" value="Change value" onclick="ChangeValueFromJs()" >

@code
{
public string TestValue {get;set;} = "init value";
}
```

js

```
function ChangeValueFromJs()
{

}
```

Is there a way to update `TestValue` and successfully bind it to text input using js `ChangeValueFromJs`?

I tried doing this, but it didn't seem to work

```
function ChangeValueFromJs()
{
     DotNet.invokeMethodAsync("BlazorApp", "invokeFromJS", "ChangeValue");
}

@code
{
    [JSInvokable("invokeFromJS")]
    public static Task ChangeValue()
    {
          TestValue = "New value";
          return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are not getting any errors, then most likely is that the value is being updated, but you need a call to `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` inside `ChangeValue()` to let Blazor know something has changed and it needs to re-render.

Comment: I cannot call InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged) inside a static method

Comment: of course you are right, my mistake not reading it correctly. you would need to change your interop to call an instance method which means you would have to pass a dotnet instance to JS initially, which is messy. I prefer to keep things simple - in your javascript, set the value on the input and then use dispatchEvent to raise the change event on the input and Blazor will update the TestValue through binding

Comment: Could you provide me an example on how to use dispatchEvent in this case

Comment: In its simplest form without any error handling, `var el=document.getElementById('xyz123'); el.value = 'test value'; el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));` where `xyz123` is the id of your `input`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I tried doing this, but it didn't seem to work

You're almost there. In order to invoke an instance method, you need to [pass the instance reference to Javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0#instance-method-call).

#### How-to

Wrap the `onclick="ChangeValueFromJs()"` with a C# delegate that will pass this component as a reference to js:

```
<input type="button" value="Change value" 
    onclick="ChangeValueFromJs()"
    @onclick='async (e) => await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync("ChangeValueFromJs", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this))' 
/gt;
```

And then change the js to invoke the instance method in following way:

```js
function ChangeValueFromJs(wrapper)
{
    return wrapper.invokeMethodAsync("invokeFromJS")
        .then(_=>{
            console.log('state has changed');
        });
}
```

Finally, don't forget to add a `StateHasChanged();` to notify the component

```
[JSInvokable("invokeFromJS")]
public Task ChangeValue()
{
    TestValue = "New value";
    StateHasChanged(); 
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

#### Demo

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can call Blazor Component method from JS following these steps:

Here is what I did to load new values in my component listPages by using my component method **loadListPagesAsync** from JS onScroll event.

1- create a reference to your component in JS, I use initdotNetListPageHelperObj function to make a reference to my dotNetListPageHelper
JS:

```
var dotNetListPageHelperObj;   
function initdotNetListPageHelperObj(dotNetListPageHelper){
    dotNetListPageHelperObj = dotNetListPageHelper;
};
```

2- I call this method when I initialise the component in Blazor:

Blazor code of my component **ListPages**:

```
private DotNetObjectReference<ListPages>? dotNetListPageHelper;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
   dotNetListPageHelper = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
JS.InvokeVoidAsync("initdotNetListPageHelperObj", dotNetListPageHelper);
}
public void Dispose()
{
  dotNetListPageHelper?.Dispose();
}
```

3- make my function Invokable

Blazor code of my component **ListPages**:

```
[JSInvokable]
public void loadListPagesAsync(string pageNumIndex)
{
  loadListPages(Int32.Parse( pageNumIndex));
}
```

4- JS: I call my method by using dotNetListPageHelperObj and I pass a parameter lastPageVisible:

```
dotNetListPageHelperObj.invokeMethodAsync('loadListPagesAsync', lastPageVisible);
```

Using this method I can update my Blazor component ListPages and invoke loadListPagesAsync to load new pages related to lastPageVisible

I hope that this will help someone.